# Playing youtube in full screen in WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, youtube, browser

I have following XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Grid>

    <WebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser1"/>

</Grid>
```

I try to play youtube video. This is what I have tried:

```
this.webBrowser1.Source = new Uri("http://youtube.googleapis.com/v/L8bE5-g8VC0");
```

This one displays YouTube player with all player controls. However full screen button doesn't work. I click on it, but player doesn't go full screen. Button becomes just disabled.

I have also tried this one:

```
this.webBrowser1.Source = new Uri("http://www.youtube.com/embed/L8bE5-g8VC0");
```

This also display YouTube player with all player controls. Full screen button is working properly. However when I go again to this video or another one (by setting Source property), player buttons disappear. To see player buttons again, I need to delete temporary internet files for IE. I could delete temp files every time before playing video, but this is not solution for me.

I'm running Windows 7 64bit and using WPF 4.0. What I want is to display YouTube player in my WebBrowser and have full screen button working properly. Anyone have some idea?

Comment: I don't know the answer. But I think two ways to do it. 1) Take screen resolution of current pc and expand the size of webBrowser with GDI+/WPF or something... 2) Try to do it with javascript which webbrowser component can handle that js code to raise fullscreen that embed flash object. Interesting question bytheway..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solution, which worked for me - building a small HTML page with embedded video player:

```
public static class WebBrowserExtensions
{
    private static string GetYouTubeVideoPlayerHTML(string videoCode)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        const string YOUTUBE_URL = @"http://www.youtube.com/v/";

        sb.Append("<html>");
        sb.Append("    <head>");
        sb.Append("        <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width; height=device-height;\">");
        sb.Append("    </head>");
        sb.Append("    <body marginheight=\"0\" marginwidth=\"0\" leftmargin=\"0\" topmargin=\"0\" style=\"overflow-y: hidden\">");
        sb.Append("        <object width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\">");
        sb.Append("            <param name=\"movie\" value=\"" + YOUTUBE_URL + videoCode + "?version=3&amp;rel=0\" />");
        sb.Append("            <param name=\"allowFullScreen\" value=\"true\" />");
        sb.Append("            <param name=\"allowscriptaccess\" value=\"always\" />");
        sb.Append("            <embed src=\"" + YOUTUBE_URL + videoCode + "?version=3&amp;rel=0\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\"");
        sb.Append("                   width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" allowscriptaccess=\"always\" allowfullscreen=\"true\" />");
        sb.Append("        </object>");
        sb.Append("    </body>");
        sb.Append("</html>");

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    public static void ShowYouTubeVideo(this WebBrowser webBrowser, string videoCode)
    {
        if(webBrowser == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("webBrowser");

        webBrowser.NavigateToString(GetYouTubeVideoPlayerHTML(videoCode));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
this.webBrowser1.ShowYouTubeVideo("L8bE5-g8VC0");
```