# WKWebView Mac Browser Enable fullscreen html5?

Tags: xcode, macos, html5-video, fullscreen, wkwebview

I made a simple browser with Swift last version and xcode 8.3.3.
I want to be able to enter in fullscreen when there is an html5 video (like on youtube).
I get "full screen is unavailable" on youtube right now.
Same problem with the old WebView... on iOS it work.

EDIT. Maybe it's just not possible. I tried to look at JavaFX WebView and WPF WebBrowser and they have the same limitation. Actually one guy was able to allow full screen for a youtube video on WPF WebBrowser but only by creating a full html page:
[Playing youtube in full screen in WebBrowser control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11329484/playing-youtube-in-full-screen-in-webbrowser-control/11383374#11383374)

And of course I cannot create a webpage for every video in a page (at least I don't know how, if you know please tell me).

---

ORIGINAL MESSAGE:
I made a simple browser with Swift last version and xcode 8.3.3.
Everything is working but I'm not able to activate plugins like I can do with the old WebView.
Since I'm on a mac I should be able to activate plugins (I understand that it's not possible on iOS) am I wrong?

Also (and here I got the same problem in the old WebView) there is no way to activate fullscreen for html5 videos (at least I don't know how).

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
let urlString = "http://myurl.com/"
self.webView.load(NSURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: urlString)! as URL) as URLRequest!)
self.webView.configuration.preferences.plugInsEnabled = true
```

This is the really basic code to get a basic browser working. But there is no option to enable plugin in the Interface Builder for WKWebView and I really don't know how to allow fullscreen for html5 videos (like youtube).

EDIT. Ok I finally found an answer for the plugin part:
    self.webView.configuration.preferences.plugInsEnabled = true

really easy but it was difficult to understand where to find it I had to go here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/webpreferences
and take a guess...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To allow `WKWebView` to use fullscreen HTML you need to access private API's (see https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/WebKit/UIProcess/API/Cocoa/WKPreferences.mm#L232-L240) in `WKPreferences`. Since you're using Swift in your bridging header add:

```c
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface WKPreferences ()
-(void)_setFullScreenEnabled:(BOOL)fullScreenEnabled;
@end
```

And simply call it:

```swift
let webView = WKWebView(frame: view.frame)
webView.configuration.preferences._setFullScreenEnabled(true)
```

If you notice strange resizing of the web view once you exit fullscreen I found that this fixes the issue for me:

```swift
webView.autoresizingMask = [.width, .height]
view.addSubview(webView)

webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
webView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
webView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
```

Note: Since you're accessing private API this would be rejected on the Mac App Store.

Comment: After all this time I did not expect a great answer (and a right one too). I don't even use a mac as my main os anymore but I used it to try your answer. Thank you, this works. Not sure why apple does not make this public API, it's just what it's needed to fix the html5 player in the webview.

Comment: Awesome solution, thanks @Soneé John! I noticed that the `webView` seemed slightly different after making this change. I ended up using the [Safari 11](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/parse/619875-safari-macos-webkit) (MacOS) user agent - it worked as expected. But, the default user agent didn't load videos. And, the chrome 70 (MacOS) user agent didn't load all of the photos.

Comment: @TheAltruist it appears your github page is gone?  I tried to look at your documentation, but github is telling me the page cannot be found.

Comment: @SouthernYankee65, I changed usernames and deleted my old repositories but I was able to recover the contents that are related to this post and added it as an answer.

Answer (score 10):

## Update for macOS 12.3

Starting on **iOS 15.4** and **macOS 12.3** `WKPreferences` has the new property `isElementFullscreenEnabled`. Now it is very simple:

```swift
myWebView.configuration.preferences.isElementFullscreenEnabled = true
```

## Original answer (pre macOS 12.3)

Instead of using private APIs you can do this by changing the property with KVO in the configuration.

Using Swift 5:

```swift
let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
configuration.preferences.setValue(true, forKey: "fullScreenEnabled")
let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)
```

Tested on macOS 10.15 and 11

Comment: Thank you!  I got my code working using this.  Now, it looks like the webView is a scrollView and has scroll bars on it.  Is there an easy way to disable the scroll bars on the webView using KVO?

Comment: I should have clarified.  The webView has horizontal and vertical scroll bars on it when not in full screen mode.

Comment: Seems to me like the content might be larger than the WebView, or maybe it is zoomed. Maybe you would like to create a new question with more details for that issue @SouthernYankee65 ?

Answer (score 2):

The solution posted by **@SoneeJohn** was clear, but it involved using a bridging header. I'd never manually worked with Objective-C or modified private Swift frameworks before. I didn't know what keywords to use. And, the resources I found seemed more involved and focused on creating an original framework - not altering an existing framework. I don't know if this is the proper implementation, but it got full-screen mode to work in web view.

### Steps

There are photos that reference each of the following steps in the next section.

1. Click your "Project" in XCode
2. Click "Add a target"
3. Click "Cocoa Framework"
4. Click "Next"
5. Enter a title into "Product Name"
6. Click "Finish"
7. Click "Add items" in "Linked Frameworks and Libraries"
8. Enter "WebKit" into the "Search"
9. Click "WebKit.framework"
10. Click "Add"
11. Click your "Project.h" file
12. Add the "Import" code from the solution

```
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>
```

13. Add the "Full Screen" code from the solution

```
@interface WKPreferences ()
-(void)_setFullScreenEnabled:(BOOL)fullScreenEnabled;
@end
```

14. Import your "Project Framework" into your swift file
15. Implement the "Full Screen" code into your web view

```
webView.configuration.preferences._setFullScreenEnabled(true)
```

15. I had to change my user agent to Safari 11 for the full-screen mode to work properly.

```
webView.customUserAgent = """
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13) AppleWebKit/604.1.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Safari/604.1.31
"""
```

Comment: I cannot test this solution (I don't own a mac anymore), but I thank you for your answer. Years ago it was really impossible to find this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that there is no answer. No API right now on mac to get fullscreen html5. I tried to make the same app on windows and the current WebView of UWP is able to go fullscreen (the old WebBrowser of WPF is not able to go fullscreen).

I think the only way to get it, it's to submit a feedback to apple.

Comment: Nothing new on macOS 10.13.4. Such a shame for mac os developers.

Comment: see the Soneé John answer. There is really no public API to make fullscreen work, but there is a private API that you can use.